# What is the Laplacian of $k\hat{r}$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $k$ is a constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields

Using 3D cylindrical coordinates, I get 0 as the answer.

$$ \nabla^{2} (k \hat{r}) = \hat{r} (\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial (k)}{\partial r}\right) + 0 + 0) + \hat{\phi} [\nabla^{2}(0)] + \hat{z} [\nabla^{2}(0)]= 0$$

Am I correct? (Edit: I'm not)

The solution to this question in the book that I'm using has ignored the unit vector and has given the Laplacian of $kr$ instead which is $k/r$.

Edit: Directly applying $\nabla^2\mathbf A=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf A)-\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf A$ gave me the answer $\frac{-k}{r^2} \hat{r}$ which is correct according to the expression for vector Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates given on page 60 of this pdf: https://ws.engr.illinois.edu/sitemanager/getfile.asp?id=135
Thanks everyone for the replies.

Comment: k is a constant.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I entered the wrong unit vectors. Edited. Had entered the unit vectors for spherical polar coordinates earlier by mistake.

Comment: Are you using r for ρ? $\hat r$ is different in the [standard conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system).

Comment: At the very least you can use the Cartesian coordinate translation...

Comment: Yes, I am using r for ρ.

Comment: OK, write $\hat \rho$ in Cartesian coordinates, and note it is a function of $\phi$. How does the cylindrical laplacian act on each component? What is your final answer?

Comment: Wow, that is very lengthy.

Comment: It is a one liner. The Laplacian is a scalar operator, so...

Comment: The Laplacian is a scalar operator but the question calls for the vector Laplacian operator. I'm probably spending too much time on a typo in a book. Lol.

Comment: If the argument of the Laplacian is a Cartesian vector, in any coordinates, each component acts like a scalar argument of the Laplacian, naturally: check each part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is complicated by the fact that you operate with the Laplacian on a vector. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Vector_Laplacian):

> The vector Laplace operator, also denoted by $\nabla^2$, is a
> differential operator defined over a vector field.[6] The vector
> Laplacian is similar to the scalar Laplacian; whereas the scalar
> Laplacian applies to a scalar field and returns a scalar quantity, the
> vector Laplacian applies to a vector field, returning a vector
> quantity. When computed in orthonormal Cartesian coordinates, the
> returned vector field is equal to the vector field of the scalar
> Laplacian applied to each vector component.
>
> The vector Laplacian of a vector field $\mathbf A$ is defined as
> $$\nabla^2\mathbf A=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf A)-\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf A$$ In Cartesian coordinates, this
> reduces to the much simpler form as $$\nabla^2\mathbf A=(\nabla^2 A_x,\nabla^2 A_y,\nabla^2 A_z)^T$$

So, because you act on a vector you can't use the usual formula for the Laplacian in polar coordinates. But the Cartesian form is still straightforward (although cumbersome). For the x-component you will get
$$-\frac{x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}$$
I checked this with Mathematica. What do you get when you write is as $$c\frac{\hat r}{r^n}?$$
With $c$ a constant and $n$ a natural number.

Comment: That makes my approach completely wrong and riddled with misunderstandings, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the explanaton. I understand now.

Comment: $\nabla^2\mathbf A=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf A)-\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf A$ gave me the answer $\frac{-k}{r^2} \hat{r}$

Comment: The answer is correct according to the expression for vector Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates given on page 60 of this pdf: https://ws.engr.illinois.edu/sitemanager/getfile.asp?id=135

Answer (score 0):

In [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), where each vector component may be thought of as an independent function,
$$
\hat \rho = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi \\ \sin \phi \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
$$
strictly a function of $\phi$; since the (scalar!) [Laplacian on such functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Line_and_volume_elements) is merely ${1\over \rho^2} \partial_\phi^2$,
it simply follows that
$$
\nabla^2 \hat \rho= -{1\over \rho^2} \hat \rho ~.
$$

Comment: I got $\frac{-k}{r^2} \hat{r}$

Comment: I just directly used this expression: $\nabla^2\mathbf A=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf A)-\nabla\times\nabla\times\mathbf A$ and solved it.

Comment: My answer is correct according to the expression for vector Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates given on page 60 of this pdf: https://ws.engr.illinois.edu/sitemanager/getfile.asp?id=135

Comment: Constants commute with differential operators, so k is superfluous here and simplifies out. Once you have the scalar laplacian, you don’t need to effectively recompute it….